# Android Studio Can not generate signed APK file

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

Everybody,  im trying to  generate  a signed APK file , with android studio, Firts of all, I changed the "Build variant"  from debug to release, then on grade.app minifyEnabled i put true,  finally I created  my Key and my password, and everything is alright until here, but on my last click, Android studio trys to generate  the file but this  message comes out

> Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
>
> Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
>   You probably need to update the library versions.
>            (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
>   :app:proguardRelease FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
>   java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
>
> Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

im too new  with this software , so  please be patient with me,  i dont know  which libraries should i Update.
My compileSdkVersion is 23, and my targed sdk version is 23.

Thanks you all of you.

here is my build.grade file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.manuelrios.aplicacion_inmobiliaria"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
}
```

Comment: Paste your build.grade file

Comment: Seems fine syntactically. Try running `./gradlew clean assembleRelease -d` and see what exception you get, if any. The only other thing I can see is that your version of play services is pretty old. The latest version is 7.8.0 or greater by now. Try changing that too.

Comment: solved, i put -dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.android.volley.toolbox.**

Comment: @NicoleArévalo, you should put that comment as an answer and then accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your app gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    .        
    .
    .
    lintOptions {
         checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}
```