# Android Studio Generate Signed apk not working2

Tags: java, android, proguard

I used older android studio version to built my app and now I have the last version.When I want make signed apk I give errors because I want to use proguard and proguard-rules.pro is not exists.I built it manually in app folder but I still encountering errors.When I remove `'proguard-rules.pro'` into **build.gradle** the problem is solving but I want to use proguard with rules because sum classes and sum files not working when `minifyEnabled` is `true` and `'proguard-rules.pro'` is removed from this code `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` into **build.gradle**.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Hossein\Desktop\Root\app\proguard-rules.pro (The system cannot find the file specified)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: What directory is the proguard-rules.pro file in?

Comment: It's in Root\app\ directory

Comment: Try this it solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/62654181/8663316

Answer (score 2):

Add into the `Root\app\` of your project a file called `proguard-rules.pro` and sign your app again.

Comment: did you tried adding the file here: C:\Users\Hossein\Desktop\Root\app\proguard-rules.pro ?

Comment: Clean your project, and create a new .apk file

Comment: I cleaned the project, rebuilt the project, closed and opened android studio, but they had no effect.