# .apk not signed error. Would like unsigned build type

Tags: android

I am trying to make a new build type that has a different resource directory than the existing debug type. This is the code that I add to my build.gradle.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
    }
    Test {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
    }
}
```

When building the'test' type Android Studio throws this error.

[image]

I've found posts that suggests including a some signing configuration in the gradle file.

```
signingConfigs{
unsigned{
    storePassword = ""
    keyAlias = ""
    keyPassword = ""
}

buildTypes{
    ...
    test {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.unsigned
    }
    ...
}
```

But adding...

> signingConfig signingConfigs.unsigned

...results in an error as the "signingConfig" datatype can't be found.

Comment: You need to create a key and a keystore. http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: I should have been clearer. I want this build type to be unsigned, like the default 'debug' type. I doing this because I want two debug builds with different resource directories to store information about their test environment.

Comment: Maybe we don't need to specify a `signingConfig` in your buildTypes entry `test`

Comment: @eee I appreciate your answer. I gave it a try. I can build the app in the 'Test' build type, but I get the error pictured above when I try to run it on my device.

Comment: The default debug type is signed. It is an automatically generated certificate that Android studio uses. It expires one year after Android studio was installed. http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#overview

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting fact. Do you know how I can configure my new 'Test' build type to use the generated certificate.

Comment: @JoshTaylor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780847/gradle-signing-app-with-packagerelease-specified-for-property-signingconfig-st