# Failed to generating Signed apk from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, signed-apk

while generating signed apk from android studio getting error. 
Few days later all works good, while from last 2 days I am facing problem to generate signed apk.

Error is -

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   What went wrong:
>
> A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageRelease'.
>   File '/media/user86/data/MySIPonline/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-release-stripped.ap_' specified for property 'resourceFile' does not exist.

I'll checked that folder and release-stripped.ap file is present in it.
I am not able to figure out the error.

Here is build.gradle (app)

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxxxxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 15
    versionName "1.5.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
}}


repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }}



dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.3'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile files('libs/paynimo_v2.0_live.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile files('libs/paynimo.scanner.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services
```

Here is link for pro-guard file - https://gist.github.com/Sanwal13/b667326812b87702c86fa02870b28240

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: check out here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629723/signingconfig-storefile-does-not-exist-when-i-try-to-run-the-project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\build\intermediates\res\resources-anzhi-debug-stripped.ap\_' specified for property 'resourceFile' does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540676/build-intermediates-res-resources-anzhi-debug-stripped-ap-specified-for-prope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow below steps to remove you error -**

**Step 1 :** - Clean your project

**Step 2 :** - Rebuild your project

**Step 3 :** - Invalidate and Restart Android Studio

**Step 4 :** - Edit build.gradle with below code

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

**Just remove** - this line

> shrinkResources false

Problem solve :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `shrinkResources` property to false as it doesn't work with `Instant Run` feature. If you are using **Android Studio 2.2** simply specify it in your manifest as:

```
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    shrinkResources false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

if you are using **Android Studio 2.0**

1. Open Settings.
2. Select Build, Execution and Deployment.
3. Uncheck enable Instant Run option.

Answer (score 0):

clean your project and try to generate signed APK i have the same issue i clean the project rebuilt the project it work for me.